${mod.id}:55061 Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '__vite__injectQuery' has already been declared (at ${mod.id}:55061:1)
I am working on a react project using vite v5.2.0. Everything was working fine until I suddenly got this error:
${mod.id}:55061  Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier '__vite__injectQuery' has already been declared (at ${mod.id}:55061:1)

I don't understand what happened, but my entire screen went white, and I am unable to do anything.

Hi @Fardeen, was this working previously? If it is throwing this error after a change, what is that change? If no changes were made, check node/npm/yarn versions and reinstall packages.. what all have you checked for, so far to debug this issue?

Thanks for replying;I accidently  import the "preview" from the vite in one of my component which is causing this error.After removing the import statement my application starts working

it may be due to an unintentional/unwanted import in one of your files; that was the issue found (now resolved) in this github thread

i have got the same issue, and i solved it by just removing an unintentionally imported vite module.

import { send } from 'vite';
I have imported this module by mistake and that's why it was giving me the error.
You can remove the file(You may import another type of file. So it is better to type ctrl+shift+f and search "from 'vite'".Then you can delete the redundant imports.)

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

The reasons you are getting the error might be due to accidentally importing unwanted things from other packages. In my case, I downloaded a build from 'vite', which I didn't need for my entire project. After deleting that line, everything returned to normal. The solution is to find the unnecessary package and delete it.

search
import { build } from "vite"

using ctrl+shift+f and remove it from the code.
